# Transaction Log file size is increasing in my Azure (IAAS) SQL Server 2014 database

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log, azure-vm

Recently we have migrated our application (both web app and database) to Azure (IASS). There we have a VM with SQL Server 2014 installed. Also I have restored all the necessary databases and SQL Server jobs on the server (from the existing On-Premise DB server). All the settings are verified and the application was working fine for a week.

Then we noticed a problem with the log file size (size is increasing  and reached around 42 GB and not able to execute any of the basic query and everything breaks :( ). The same DB and Job ran in on-premise server for a year and  this issue didn't happen.

Some information about the application and DB

- The application contains a couple of SQL scheduling jobs which run each 2 hours of a day and the job take maximum of 5-8 minutes to complete.
- Application contains less than 200 users and concurrent users are around 20-30.

So please let me know any one of your comments/input on this (Transaction log file size increment) issue. Also please let me know if you need any other information

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever do a full database backup?  That will zap the log, which is what you're looking for.  See [T-SQL BACKUP command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) for syntax.  Not sure what backups look like on Azure, but that should help.